# Xcode crashes when moving to plist tab

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I don't know why but when clicking on the plist tab in the Xcode it crashes.

This is it:

[image]

I have tried to delete the DerivedData directory, rebuild the project, clean the build folder and some other things I don't remember.

Everything I build or prepare the project using Cordova (`cordova build ios`) (`cordova prepare ios)` the info.plist file is wiped to its default (what Apple provided).

I also have 4 directories/files of the project in the ios directory, see it here:

[image]

There is not any issue when clicking on any other tab, just the plist.

When selecting the PROJECT in the Xcode (not the TARGETS shown in the first image), I have this:

[image]

The only info plist file I have found is in the main app directory (the name of the app)

Comment: Try to open it in using `Open as Source Code` you might be missing some brackets

Answer (score 0):

Try these two steps first quit xcode click on workspace file show package contents and remove xcuserdata. In second step check if plist is valid.